# Ionic Cordova run on android device gives: Could not find apk architecture: arm build-type: debug

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

Anyone would point me anything how to fix de error?
When I run:

```
% cordova run android -l -c
```

Everything seems to be going OK but in the end it gives me this erro:

```
Built the following apk(s):

Error: Could not find apk architecture: arm build-type: debug
```

I know that must be something related to Crosswalk, but this project was running Ok before when I was using platform 6.3.0.

Here is my Ionic Info:

```
% ionic info                                                                                                                                                                     
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.4.0 ios 4.5.5
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    ios-deploy        : 2.0.0
    ios-sim           : 6.0.0
    Node              : v8.11.3
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : macOS
    Xcode             : Xcode 10.0 Build version 10A255

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : ~/Library/Android/sdk

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

And here are my plugins:

```
% cordova plugin list                                                                                                                                                        
com.googlemaps.ios 2.7.0 "Google Maps SDK for iOS"
com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions 0.6.5 "Native Page Transitions"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 1.7.1 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.0.0 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-contacts 3.0.1 "Contacts"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.4.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.7 "Device"
cordova-plugin-email-composer 0.8.15 "EmailComposer"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.10.1 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.3 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.11.0 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.3.2 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-linkedin 1.2.1 "LinkedIn"
cordova-plugin-media 5.0.2 "Media"
cordova-plugin-nativeaudio 3.0.9 "Cordova Native Audio"
cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder 2.0.5 "NativeGeocoder"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.4 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-streaming-media 2.2.0 "StreamingMedia"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.1 "SocialSharing"
cordova-sqlite-storage 0.7.14 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 6.0.8 "BarcodeScanner"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.2.3 "PushPlugin"
twitter-connect-plugin 0.6.0 "Twitter Connect"
```

**EDIT 1:**
Actually this problem is happening because after building/running the .apk files can't be found.
As you can see here there are no .apk files listed, but those apk files are there inside the folder as you can see on the picture below:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 43s
72 actionable tasks: 10 executed, 62 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):
```

**See above, no apk files listed.**

[image]

Comment: Mostly issue is happening due to crosswalk if you can't remove crosswalk then try with Ionic CLI v3 instead of using latest one

p.s. if your application is supporting then grater then android 5 devices then i guess there's no need of crosswalk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @harshzalavadiya, can you have a look at my **Edit 1** please?

Comment: yes that means it's working properly if you install crosswalk it will generate architecture specific binaries (x86, ARM etc.) so if your device is ARM you can install ARM apk only (In short once you build application it will generate multiple APKs instead of single apk) and will throw error on cordova/ionic run

Comment: But why do you think that happens? Before, it was working, even with Crosswalk, and the device is ARM, it's the same device, I must find a way to run this apk on the android device in debug with liveload just the way it was working before.

Comment: for debugging purpose you can remove crosswalk and add when creating deployable apk, because even if you can make it work for debug it will make builds slower

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error and was able to run from Android Studio. So I build with "cordova build android" and then open \platforms\android\ and run from there as a workaround.

Comment: how to run it in android device?