# Cannot find apk architecture when run command "ionic cordova run android"

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

When I run command

```
ionic cordova run android
```

build is succeeded but app cannot be run on my android device.

The error log is as:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4m 7s
47 actionable tasks: 45 executed, 2 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_121
No target specified, deploying to device 'UGM0217321003049'.
Skipping build...
Built the following apk(s):

Error: Could not find apk architecture: arm build-type: debug
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

    cordova run android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Under the directory `platforms/android/build/outputs/apk`, there is only one folder called debug under which there are two file `android-debug.apk` and `output.json`.

```
 apk
  |---debug
        |---android-debug.apk
        |---output.json
```

I suspect there should be some arm architecture file in apk directory, but I don't know how to generate it.

Can you help me to solve this run android error?

Comment: try ionic Cordova build an android that will create generic APK which will work on all devices

Comment: check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992928/ionic-cordova-run-on-android-device-gives-could-not-find-apk-architecture-arm

Comment: @shizhen Thanks. similar issue but I could not find a good answer for solving it in that question.

Comment: You can try to run `cordova build android` and manually find the apk to install.

Comment: @shizhen Thanks. The build is successful. Can you tell me where the apk is? is it android-debug.apk?

Comment: yes, should be. you can try to install it manually from `platforms\android`.

Comment: Thanks. I move the android-debug.apk from debug folder to apk folder, then run "ionic cordova run android". It works and deploy the app in my android phone then.

Comment: How to automatically build the android-debug.apk in app folder? Seem the output.json manage this, I tried to change the output.json, but it always recovers to the previous setting after run "ionic cordova run android".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid extended discussions in comments, let me summarise **the workaround** as below:

1. Try to run below command to build the apk first.

   ```
   cordova build android
   ```

   or

   ```
   ionic cordova build android
   ```
2. Look for the apk from `platforms\android` and manually install it.

> How to automatically build the `android-debug.apk` in app folder?

the `.json` file is auto generated, usually you don't need to touch it.

By default, the apk path is under `app/build/outputs/apk`, you can copy it to a custom location wherever you prefer, for your case, maybe it is `app/` root directory. You can do this with many means, e.g. bash scripts. Below gradle snippets is how I do this task, just copy below code to the end of your `app/build.gradle`:

```
def capitalizeFirstLetter(s) { s[0].toUpperCase() + s[1..-1] }

def publish = project.tasks.create("copyApks")
publish.description "Copies apks to custom directory"

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    def customPath

    variant.outputs.all {

        customPath = "$projectDir"

        def capitalizedVariantName = capitalizeFirstLetter(variant.name)
        def task = project.tasks.create("copy${capitalizedVariantName}Apk", Copy)

        task.from(outputFile)
        task.into(customPath)

        task.dependsOn variant.assemble
        publish.dependsOn task
    }
}
```

From your command line, run `./gradlew copyApks` or `gradlew copyApks` on macOS or Windows respectively.

Then you will find your apk is under `app\` directory.

Comment: thanks. Why android-debug.apk is generated in folder debug, but not apk?

Comment: There’s some changes for the apk directory for different Android grade plugin, it doesn’t really matter with above gradle scripts, you can adjust according to your version